# Eclipse IDE Sidebar (navigation) missing

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use Eclipse for my Computer Science class, except the bar on the left is missing. Does anyone know the fix?

Answer (score 34):

Do you mean the package explorer ? You can toggle it here [image]

Answer (score 13):

Try going  Window > Reset Perspective to go to the default view which should contain the project explorer

Answer (score 7):

In menu bar, you can select "Window" -> "Show View", and then select "Project Explorer" (or other components you want to open).

Answer (score 3):

I guess the **bar on the left** which OP is searching for is **Package Explorer**.

And it can be found at

`Windows` > `Show View` > `Package Explorer`

Refer the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might be in the Debug option. Click on Java instead. It is on the top right. If you reset Perspective, it won't show you the Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to the package explorer view?

Window -> show view -> package explorer

Answer (score 0):

If you're missing the Package Explorer, just go to "Window" -> "Show View" and click "Package Explorer"

Answer (score 0):

It is known as Navigator, You can find it in Window -> Show View ->  Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened in STM32 IDE (based on eclipse) I use:Window->Perspective->Reset Perspective  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Srwb.png)